# how expand EC2 node to have more storage for Cassandra

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, virtual-machine, cassandra-2.0

Hi I want to use the recommended storage for Cassandra which is 1-3 TB per node.  I am wondering how to increase the VMs to have that much hard drive space with SSD or HDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried exactly?

You can specify the EBS volume size you want when you create the EC2 instance.

You can add a new EBS volume to an existing EC2 instance.

You can grow an existing EBS volume: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

You can use multiple EBS volumes in a RAID configuration for performance and ease of increasing space: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/raid-config.html